# Finding exact matches within table

Tags: sql

Lets say we have a table with two columns, `name` and `likes`. Each `name` may have multiple `likes`.

I need a query to find the `names` that have the exact same `likes` as `name=Bob` (not fewer and contained in Bob, and not more including all of Bob's likes.)

My idea is for each `name`, join their `likes` to Bob's `likes` and check if it matches Bob's `likes` still, while also checking that each have the same number of `likes`. Any help?

Comment: What is likes? What rdbms?

Comment: You're probably looking at doing a subquery in the `where` clause, by the sounds of it.

Comment: Name and Likes are both attributes of the table. Likes in my actual problem is the brands of candy people like.

Answer (score 1):

You need a self join here.  That means join a table to itself as shown below -

```
Select distinct a.name, b.name from table as a join      table as b on a.likes = b.likes and a.name != b.name
```

Note the use of distinct clause and inequality of names to avoid a name matching with itself

This will output rows as-

```
a.name  |  b.name
----------------------------
Bob         |  John
Smith      |  Ram
```

If you want to check for a specific user as Bob,  then you can append a where clause to the query.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to concatenate the variables into a single string and compare them.  Using MySQL syntax:

```
select t.name
from (select name, group_concat(likes order by likes) as likes
      from t
      group by name
     ) t cross join
     (select group_concat(likes order by likes) as likes
      from t
      where name = 'Bob'
     ) bob
     on t.likes = bob.likes and t.name <> 'Bob';
```

Another method that will work in almost any other database is to use a join and counts:

```
select t.name
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as numlikes
      from t
      where name <> 'Bob'
     ) t cross join
     (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as numlikes
      from t
      where name = 'Bob'
    ) bob
    on t.likes = bob.likes and t.cnt = bob.cnt
group by t.name, t.cnt
having count(*) = t.cnt;  -- the number of matches is the number of likes
```